# Which bandwith can i expect, when i´m running a SATA SSD on a SAS interface?

Tags: linux, performance, ssd, sas, sata

So, i know this question had been asked before. I consider to buy a SSD for my Server, because i kinda hate the SAS HDDs in there.

I thought:
If i connect a SSD, which, in fact, handles way more than 550MB/s which the SATA6 can, to a SAS Interface, wouldn`t it be faster, because of the SAS interface?

I do not know the specific speeds of my SAS interface in this specific server, but i would work, because you CAN connect SATA to SAS.

Thanks for answers,
vortex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably get a 6Gbps link speed or a 3Gbps link speed, depending on the server, backplane and controller.

A modern SATA SSD will likely be a 6Gbps device.

But disk and storage speed isn't just about raw sequential I/O performance. The benefit of an SSD will be random I/O performance, which you're more likely to be impacted by.

Comment: But there are 12gbps interfaces. If i connect it to one of those, can i bypass the SATA6 bottleneck?

Comment: Not unless you have a 12Gbps SATA disk. SAS is a switching protocol. This is like plugging a 100Mbps device into a gigabit port.